# Ansible Lookup Plugin in Group Vars is called multiple times

Tags: python, ansible

I have written a lookup plugin to fetch passwords from a password storage API. I'm fetching e.g. hosts secrets. To avoid adding the lookup plugin call to each host seperately I just placed it in `group_vars/all.yml` like so:

```
ansible_password: "{{ lookup('some_vars') }}"
```

When I'm running a playbook (e.g. `site-ping.yml` which does nothing more than a login and ping) which is limited to only 1 host I still see how the plugin is actually called two times (and therefore two API calls are made).

`gather_facts` is set to `no`. If I set it to `yes` I will actually get 4 lookup plugin calls.

Why is that so? Are the `group_vars` in ansible initialized twice at run-time? Where should I place the lookup plugin call to avoid this? Any best-practice?

Comment: Have you tried running you playbook extra verbose to analyse this behavior? `ansible-playbook -vvvv foo.yaml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not a final solution but I found a workaround to avoid the behaviour of ansible calling the lookup plugin twice if defined in the `group_vars`. Instead of calling the lookup plugin directly for `ansible_password`, e.g.:

```
ansible_password: "{{ lookup('some_lookup_vars') }}"
```

I introduced a temp-variable like this:

```
password_lookup: "{{ lookup('some_lookup_vars') }}"
ansible_password: "{{ password_lookup }}"
```

Strange but I assume that Ansible tries to check if the variable is initialized and therefore trigger the lookup plugin. That way the lookup plugin will only be triggered once.

Edit: See also here: [#52290 Github Issue Link](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/52290)

Comment: many thanks for this workaround ! tested and it's ok :)